# Extract single file from zip archive

Tags: iphone, zip, archive, unzip

is it possible to extract single file from .zip archive using iOS sdk?)

Comment: It's certainly possible to extract the file.  Whether there's an iOS interface to do it or you'd have to use 3rd party/roll-your-own I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Minizip](http://www.winimage.com/zLibDll/minizip.html). Works just fine on iOS.

Comment: thx)decided to use objective-zip http://code.google.com/p/objective-zip/ @Martin Adoue